# A Fun Game with Coins

Tags: game-theory

Assume you have a pair number of coins $2n$ with possibly different values, ordered in a line. Let us enumerate the coins as $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n}$. The coins are not ordered in any particular way.

The game has two players and the first player has to take one coin from the extreme points (either $x_1$ or $x_{2n}$). Then, the second player has to take one coin from the extremes and so on until there are no more coins. The winner is the one who ends up with more money.

It is clear that if $n=1$ then the first player wins or draws. If $n=2$ with a little more work you can prove that the first player has a winning (or draw) strategy and the same with $n=3$.

Does the first player have a winning strategy always?

What is the *optimal* strategy to maximize the profit?

Comment: This is a classic interview question: first player can always win or draw. This is because the first player can always force the second player to pick from the even-numbered coins or from the odd-numbered coins. 

Comment: Yes! but isn't it a great and fun problem anyway? I didn't know that was a classic though. 

Comment: @Gabriel, so, wait - you already knew the first player has a winning strategy? MO isn't for questions to which you already know the answer. Please read the faq. 

Comment: @Gerry: I didn't know the answer before! I just was excited about how easy alex's solution was. @Alex: you should put your solution as answer so I can give you the credit. 

Comment: The existence of the winning/drawing strategy seems completely obvious. Now **computing** it in practice will require more care, and is probably the interesting question. Existence though, not so much.

Comment: @Gabriel, sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I still submit the puzzle has no research interest and doesn't belong on this website. For what it's worth, this is the first item in Peter Winkler's excellent book, Mathematical Puzzles. 

Comment: so maybe it is worth asking some further questions:
What is the optimal strategy (that guarantees the highest money output)?
what happens when the number of coins is odd. What is then the best strategy ? Note that then the first player might loose, as the example 1,3,1 shows.

Comment: @HenrikRüping, I added the question about the optimal strategy. I believe that there might be an interesting mathematics behind it...

Comment: Shouldn't a good winning strategy automatically steer you towards the highest possible payoff? Do you have a good example where you win without maximum payoff that cannot be easily modified to give maximal payoff?

Comment: well I have an example, where the optimal strategy is not among picking the even or the odd coins: 300,1,1,2,1,1. I guess one can also construct more involved examples.

Comment: I don't believe anyone suggested that you should take only odd or only even. But any *general* all-purpose strategy that works should work whatever the values are, and so I would find it hard to believe that it wouldn't pick out the maximum outcome. 
$$ * \quad * \quad *$$
That being said, the more I think about this problem, the more I think that even describing a winning strategy is hopeless (since the best move requires you to look ahead in the game and not just at local information).